# What are the struts connecting the roof to the rest of the car called?

Tags: part-identification, body-work

I need to have some work done on the part of the body that connects the roof to the rest of the car, and I'm wondering what is that piece of the car *called?*

[image]

If it matters, I'm specifically wondering about the piece between doors (but not on the doors themselves) on a 4-door sedan.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's the B-Pillar, the one at the front that the windshield is attached too is the A-Pillar, the one at the back after the rear door is the C-Pillar, if there was one behind that like in a station wagon or SUV it would be the D-Pillar and so on.

[More info here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillar_%28automobile%29)

[image]